# Selenium webdriver selecting items from combobox with no ID

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem. I need to obtain an item from combobox, which is filled with items from database, and there is no ID for them, so maybe someone has encountered with this problem and can help me :)

Hi all, well now i'm trying this code (sorry i'm really terrible at it :/ )

```
boolean text1 = Boolean.valueOf("//*[contains(text(), 'textA')]"); 
boolean text2 = Boolean.valueOf("//*[contains(text(), 'textA')]"); 
int i = 0; 
 do { 
     if (text1 != true){ 
       waitForElement(By.xpath("//div[@onclick='meXpatht()']")).click(); //going to next 
                                                                        //combobox page 
    } else if (text2 == true){ 
       waitForElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'textA')]")).click(); //selecting
                                                                          //combo item 
      } else { 
        //not done yet, here will be creation of new reccord
      } 
  i++; 
} 
while (i <= 1000);
```

So there is my code, i'm trying to find an element which i need, by text, when i don't find one, i go to the next combobox page.

There is a problem with that code, that i have an infinity loop now, when i load it. And I can't figure it out how to stop the loop when i find the text that I need.

Any ideas how to fix this code? or i'm doing something really wrong here?

I thought that i will be able to stop the loop with `break;` when I find an element, but it didn't worked. Now I'm thinking, maybe this is because i'm looking for text in combobox?

Comment: can you show your html structure ? and what have you tried with selenium

Comment: Thanks varun257 for the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more ways to select `WebElement` objects than just hooking onto their ID.

You can check the various ways [HERE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) but I recommend you look specifically at the **CSS Selector** which you can probably use in your situation to traverse through the DOM from the nearest element that has an ID for example.

**Example of CSS Selector from the docs I linked:**

```
WebElement cheese = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#food span.dairy.aged"));
```

You could also use the XPath selector if you are more comfortable with XPath than CSS.

**Example:**

```
List<WebElement> inputs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input"));
```

Since it seems that you are dealing with a `select` element you could also use something along the lines of this:

```
WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.tagName("select"));
List<WebElement> allOptions = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
for (WebElement option : allOptions) {
    if("yourDesiredValue".equals(option.getAttribute("value"))){
        option.click();
    }
}
```

Where `"yourDesiredValue"` is a `String` representing the value attribute of the `option` tag you wish to select.

Comment: Thanks for the help in long run it helped.